# Close question caused by spelling error?

Tags: discussion

This [question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/64659/1696) arose due to a text example containing a spelling error. Programming sections have "can not reproduce" as closing reason, which seems to be the corresponding cause, but it is not available here.

So I see 3 options:

1. leave the question open
2. close with textual description instead (quick and easy)
3. providing an additional close reason

(1) has the disadvantage, that writers of answers waste their time better spent on more useful questions, while (3) may not be worth the effort.

So any objections about going on with option (2)?

Comment: (2) seems to be good to me.

Comment: liebe*r guidot, ich bin mir nicht sicher, ob ich als question author dazu Stellung nehmen sollte. Wenn Du möchtest, kannst Du natürlich meine Frage löschen. Manchmal, wenn ich auf die Schnelle keinen Muttersprachler in meiner Umgebung finden kann, wende ich mich an Euch (das ist der Sinn des ganzen Forums, nicht wahr?). Bisher habe ich immer hilfreiche und nützliche Antworten auf meine Fragen bekommen. Btw, is there any info on what kind of questions are classified as "useful"?

Comment: @Serena: Nein, Löschen wollte ich damit nicht vorschlagen. Es ist immerhin möglich, dass jemand über denselben falschen Text stolpert und hier sucht und dann deine Frage findet. *Useful* ist für mich ein Etikett für Allgemeingültigkeit, und mit Huberts Antwort auf deine Frage ist diese ja erschöpfend beantwortet. Eine Frage zu schließen, ist aus meiner Sicht keine Abwertung und die Votes zählen weiter.

Answer (score 6):

I vote for:
**Leave the question open, answer it correctly and add some additional information so that other people can learn something from the answer.** (like I did in [my answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/64663/1487)). Becasue I think this is what this site was made for: Giving good answers to legitimate questions.

I think that it's also worth to mention, that this specific question earned 3 points and my answer earned 4 points (at the moment when I wrote this sentence) without any negative votings. So, 3 people think, that *”This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear”* and 3 people think that *”This answer is useful”.* For me these are 7 reasons to leave this question open and to leave similar questions open too in the future.